# An inequality relating the ratio of the areas of two triangles

Tags: geometry, inequality

The conjecture below is a modified version of this question:

> [Prove that, given a triangle with sides $a,b,c$, there exists a triangle with sides $a+2b,b+2c,c+2a$ that has an area three times the original](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845559)

**Conjecture:**

> If $u$ is the area of a triangle with sides $a,b,c$, and $v$ is the area of a triangle with sides $a+2b,b+2c,c+2a$, then ${\large{\frac{v}{u}}}\ge 9$.

**Remarks:**

- For the equilateral case ($a=b=c$), we get ${\large{\frac{v}{u}}}=9$.

  Limited data testing seems to support the truth of the conjecture.

  Trying to prove the claim via Heron's formula appears to be a disaster.

**Question:**$\;$Is the conjecture true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=b+c-a\geq 0$, $y=a+c-b\geq 0$, $z=a+b-c\geq 0$.
Let $p=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)$ be the semiperimeter of the triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$. Similarly let $P=\frac{1}{2}(A+B+C)=3p$ be the semiperimeter of the triangle with sides $A=b+2c$, $B=c+2a$, $C=a+2b$. Then, by Heron's formula, the inequality is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align}0&\leq \frac{v^2}{u^2}-9^2=\frac{P(P-A)(P-B)(P-C)}{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}-9^2\\&=
\frac{6((x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)+2(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2)-9xyz)}{xyz}
\end{align}$$
which holds because by the AGM inequality
$$x^2y+y^2z+z^2x\geq 3xyz\quad\mbox{and}\quad xy^2+yz^2+zx^2\geq 3xyz.$$

Comment: So Heron's formula (with some appropriate followup moves) works after all!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.